# How to handle URL Image if has non English characters SwiftUI

Tags: swift, url, swiftui

Im displaying url images in my app with WebImage but some of them has non English characters in the path so they are not displaying in view.How can I handle non English characters in Url ımage ?

case ListType.vertical.rawValue:

```
        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 20), count: data.column ?? 1), spacing:30 ) {
            
            ForEach(data.options ?? [] , id :\.id ){ item in
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewParser.create(item: item,index: item.typeArry ?? [])) {
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                        
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: item.image ?? ""))
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(CGFloat(data.ratio ?? 1),contentMode: .fit)
                            .cornerRadius(isColumnOne ? 12 : 0)
                            .padding(.horizontal , 1)
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem ;

`WebImage(url: URL(string: item.image?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed ) ?? ""))`